# adding a node in existing XML using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

**below is the demo xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TrialDemoModify3.xsl"?>
<class> 
    <students>          
     <student rollno="393">
         <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
         <lastname>Kad</lastname>
         <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
         <marks>85</marks>
     </student>
     <student rollno="493">
     <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
     <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
     <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
     <marks>95</marks>
     </student>
     <student rollno="593">
     <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
     <lastname>Singh</lastname>
     <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
     <marks>90</marks>
     </student>
```

```
 </class>
```

MY **xsl** which i am following for the demo xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        <xsl:if test="self::navigation">
            <node title="Employees">
                <node>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="group" />
                </node>
            </node>         
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@lastname=*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="lastname"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="group"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>         
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="group" />                
        </xsl:otherwise>    
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="group" />
```

my **expected output** should look like the following xml but as it does not:

```
<class> 
<students>          
     <student rollno="393">
         <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
         <lastname>Kad</lastname>
         <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
         <marks>85</marks>
     </student>
     <student rollno="493">
     <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
     <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
     <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
     <marks>95</marks>
     </student>
     <student rollno="593">
     <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
     <lastname>Singh</lastname>
     <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
     <marks>90</marks>
     </student>
```

```
<Employees>
<Employee><lastname>Kad</lastname></Employee>
<Employee><lastname>Gupta</lastname></Employee>
<Employee><lastname>Singh</lastname></Employee>
 </Employees>
</class>
```

I have already spent my last three days on this code. this is just a demo code but even that is not working for that.
Please help...i am **unable to get the expected output**....instead my **xml stays as it is**.
Thanks

Comment: In the Input XML, `</students>` tag is missing and in the output `<Employees>` tag is used but it is not used in Input XML. Please update question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick answer.

With below XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
<class>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<Employees>
<xsl:for-each select="/class/students/student/lastname">
<Employee>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</Employee>
</xsl:for-each>
</Employees>
</class>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces below Output:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class>
    <students>
        <student rollno="393">
            <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
            <lastname>Kad</lastname>
            <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
            <marks>85</marks>
        </student>
        <student rollno="493">
            <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
            <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
            <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
            <marks>95</marks>
        </student>
        <student rollno="593">
            <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
            <lastname>Singh</lastname>
            <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
            <marks>90</marks>
        </student>
    </students>
    <Employees>
        <Employee>
            <lastname>Kad</lastname>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <lastname>Singh</lastname>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.....solved my problem....can i have an explanation of this xslt that you have made....what error was i making....i hope m not asking for much....thanks